# Photoshop CS6 marquee in normal style has width and height greyed out

Tags: adobe-photoshop, marquee-tool

All of a sudden I can't type width and height of a marquee in the top bar. The document is a standard JPG, no quick mask modes, (single) layer is normal and unlocked. The Fixed Ratio and Size styles are **not** affected; it's only the Normal style that seems to be afflicted.

I've restarted Photoshop several times, and even the computer itself, but to no avail. Any suggestion?

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to add width or height when the style is `Normal`. You need to pick `Fixed Size` and then you can add width and height.

Answer (score 1):

In Normal mode the Width and Height options are not useable. This is by design. This is so you can use the marquee tool to freely select a size or ratio.

[image: Normal Mode]

In Fixed Ratio you can choose a ratio for your selection to draw out at.

[image: Fixed Ratio]

In Fixed Size mode you can enter in a height and width for your selection.

[image: Fixed Size]